# Why some classes define injections in both their constructor and di.xml?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, dependency-injection, di

I don't understand why, in some classes, their dependency injections are declared twice - once in the `di.xml` and in the concrete class's constructor.

For instance in `Magento\Backend\Model\Url`, its `di.xml` has this set of types for DI defined:

```
<type name="Magento\Backend\Model\Url">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="scopeResolver" xsi:type="object">
Magento\Backend\Model\Url\ScopeResolver</argument>
        <argument name="authSession" xsi:type="object">
Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session\Proxy</argument>
        <argument name="formKey" xsi:type="object">
Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Proxy</argument>
        <argument name="scopeType" xsi:type="const">
Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE </argument>
        <argument name="backendHelper" xsi:type="object">
Magento\Backend\Helper\Data\Proxy</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

But at the same time, in its concrete class, those classes defined in di.xml required for injection is re-declared again in the constructor:

```
<?php
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Route\ConfigInterface $routeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        \Magento\Framework\Url\SecurityInfoInterface $urlSecurityInfo,
        \Magento\Framework\Url\ScopeResolverInterface $scopeResolver,
        \Magento\Framework\Session\Generic $session,
        \Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolverInterface $sidResolver,
        \Magento\Framework\Url\RouteParamsResolverFactory $routeParamsResolverFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Url\QueryParamsResolverInterface $queryParamsResolver,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        $scopeType,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Config $menuConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\App\CacheInterface $cache,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession,
        \Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface $encryptor,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreFactory $storeFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
        array $data = []
) {
    //...
}
?>
```

If we look at its constructor above, `\Magento\Framework\App\Route\ConfigInterface $routeConfig`, for example, is not defined in `di.xml`. It is only defined in the constructor and Magento will still inject the `routeConfig` into the class for use, wouldn't it? Same for `\Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface $encryptor` and a few others.

Then, why is there a need to define the other injections in both `di.xml` and in the constructor when having those declarations in the constructor is sufficient for Magento to inject those dependencies into the class for use?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[As stated in the documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/build/di-xml-file.html#constructor-arguments), in Magento 2, the `di.xml` can be used to do the following:

> You can configure the class constructor arguments in your `di.xml` in
>   the argument node. The object manager injects these arguments into the
>   class during creation. The name of the argument configured in the XML
>   file must correspond to the name of the parameter in the constructor
>   in the configured class.

In your case it's slightly complex I'm going to explain each argument one by one:

- `\Magento\Framework\App\Route\ConfigInterface $routeConfig` : this is **an interface so it's not usable directly**. The **preference for this class is defined in `app/etc/di.xml`** and it is the `Magento\Framework\App\Route\Config` class
- `\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request` : same goes for this class, the preference is `Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http`
- `\Magento\Framework\Url\SecurityInfoInterface $urlSecurityInfo` : same case here again with `Magento\Framework\Url\SecurityInfo\Proxy` as the preference
- `\Magento\Framework\Url\ScopeResolverInterface $scopeResolver` : here we start with the interesting bit. **In `app/etc/di.xml` a preference is defined for this interface and it is the `Magento\Framework\Url\ScopeResolver` class. However, for the `Magento\Backend\Model\Url` Magento 2 needs to use another class and thus it defines which class in the `di.xml` you posted so `Magento\Backend\Model\Url\ScopeResolver` will be used.**
- `\Magento\Framework\Session\Generic $session` this is a normal class and thus can be used as it.
- `\Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolverInterface $sidResolver` : back to an interface, the preference is still defined in `app/etc/di.xml` and it is `Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolver\Proxy`
- `\Magento\Framework\Url\RouteParamsResolverFactory $routeParamsResolverFactory` : this is a factory class so it can be used as it.
- `\Magento\Framework\Url\QueryParamsResolverInterface
  $queryParamsResolver` : back to our `app/etc/di.xml` and the preference is `Magento\Framework\Url\QueryParamsResolver`
- `\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig` : another case here where **a preference is defined in `app/etc/di.xml` and it is `Magento\Framework\App\Config` .
- `$scopeType` : here we only have a variable without any class in front of it. Your module `di.xml` specifies that `Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE` should be used as the value of this variable.**
- `\Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper` : here we could have use that class as it. **However here a proxy is used because this class is not necessarily being used (see this post for details about proxy classes: [Magento 2: practical explanation of what is a proxy class?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/143070/2380) )**
- `\Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Config $menuConfig` : we can use this class as it.
- `\Magento\Framework\App\CacheInterface $cache` : another preference defined in `app/etc/di.xml` for this interface which is `Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Proxy`
- `\Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession` : **same again here we could have used the class as it but we use a proxy class instead for lazy loading.**
- `\Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface $encryptor` : jumping to the `app/etc/di.xml` again and we find `Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor` as a preference
- `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreFactory $storeFactory` : a factory so we can use it as it.
- `\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey` : **here we use a the `Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Proxy` proxy class again for lazy loading.**
- `array $data = []` : this one always comes last and is automatically defaulted to an empty array you can find more information here: [Magento 2: what is the $data array constructor parameter?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/118033/2380)

**To summarize**

Globally, classes constructors parameters are interfaces or non instantiable classes. Thus `di.xml` lets you tailor the dependencies you want to use for each class constructor. It's also valid for instantiable classes. For example a class constructor that takes a product class as a constructor argument. It can be tailored in the configurable product module so it takes a configurable product class instead as an argument.

Comment: Is a preference always required for an interface parameter? Can it be seen as a fallback? Does it make sense to just define a concrete argument in the configuration without having a preference anywhere? Or is that not possible?

Answer (score 6):

It is important to understand the difference between **definition** of dependencies and **configuration** of dependencies.

Dependencies are not defined inside di.xml. Dependencies are **defined inside the constructor** of the respective class by specifying an interface, an abstract or a factory as the **type** of that specific dependecy, e.g. `$routeConfig` is a dependency of type `\Magento\Framework\App\Route\ConfigInterface`.

On the other hand, **`di.xml` is the place to configure the dependencies** by using `<preference/>` nodes and/or `xpath:type/arguments/argument` nodes (sometimes coupled with more advanced configuration nodes like `<virtualType/>` or `<proxy/>`). Configuring a dependency simply means **mapping an object's constructor argument to an implementation/object/concrete**.

You want dependencies to be **configurable via di.xml** so that you can swap them and use a **different implementation** for a **certain interface** or argument **under certain conditions** (keep reading the example to understand what certain conditions is supposed to mean).

For example, when developing your extension you would first create a new class (we call this new class an **implementation**). Your new class implements the `\Magento\Framework\App\Route\ConfigInterface` interface and it has inside its body a concrete functionality which honors the interface contract. **Now starts the configuration part**: in order to tell Magento to use your newly defined implementation you must **configure this implementation as a dependecy for the object** `Magento\Backend\Model\Url`. You do this **configuration** inside the `di.xml` files or your module. In this case you need to use the `<preference/>` node to map the interface to your new implementation. Other times you would use the more granular `xpath:type/arguments/argument` `di.xml` node to **map only specific arguments (a.k.a. dependencies, a.k.a interfaces) of a concrete to specific implementations**. Now, **your implementation will only be active** as a dependency for the object `\Magento\Backend\Model\Url` **in certain conditions**, e.g., in the code execution flow of the current application request an object of type `Magento\Backend\Model\Url` is being created and it needs an implementation for the **constructor defined** dependency called `$routeConfig` which is of type `\Magento\Framework\App\Route\ConfigInterface`.

It is pretty much like saying:

*"Hey Mr. ObjectManager! Whenever an object instance of type `Magento\Backend\Model\Url` is requested, please have a look at its class **constructor definition** first and analyze the **dependecies defined** therein. I want you then to lookup inside the final, merged `di.xml` of the current HTTP request the **configuration** for each and every **configured dependency** that is **defined** in the **Magento\Backend\Model\Url class constructor**. You give me **that** configured dependency implementation."*